# regular expressions: catch any URLs of the domain example.com

Tags: regex

I'm trying to get regexp code for the below case. I tried multiple tries but in vain.
I need to catch any URLs of the domain site.com. Tried using regexp '**^site.com/*$**
but it does not recognizes it.

i'm just looking for regexp code whichmatches  site.com/*

Comment: Hi. Please add more context to your question. Are you talking about web server rewriting, some coding project, or matching using a tool or service?  Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and especially [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) and then edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your expression `^site.com/*$` you match all strings that start with `site.com` and have zero or more trailing `/` characters (`/*`):

[image]

If you want to match any strings starting with `site.com/` you might want to try `^site\.com/.*$`:

[image]

There are already a lot of other regex questions regarding domain names on SO, but your question is not clear to me in what context you are trying to do this, or what is the actual goal you want to achieve. If you describe your needs more precisely you could probably find some answers on this forum.

Answer (score 0):

I generally use a helper website like regex101.com.

Also, a few things to note, `.` has a special meaning in regex meaning any character, and if you wanted to capture `site.com/foo` you might want to use something where you are not limited to the number of characters by the end.  I'd do this with groupings.

```
^(site\.com\/)(.+)$
```

You can see this in action here: https://regex101.com/r/AU2iYC/2

Answer (score 0):

Your regex `^site.com/*$` is only matched follow sentences

ex) site.com/ site.com//////// site.com

because `*` asterisk in regex means `Match 0 or more of the preceding token.`

so, it should be work

`^site.com\/.*$`